Why does explicitly setting `filetype plugin indent on` in neovim have an effect?
I'm using neovim 0.10.1 where filetype plugin indent on is a default value and supposedly not necessary anymore in init.vim. However, explicitly setting it makes my
In my init.vim I add compatibility with vim by adding to the runtime and sourcing my vimrc:
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath = &runtimepath
source ~/.vimrc

In ~/.vimrc I have set textwidth=0 which is overridden in ftplugin/lua.vim to set textwidth=80. When I open a .lua file, the textwidth is unexpectedly 0, last set by my vimrc according to :verbose set textwidth?. So apparently the vimrc command overrides the lua.vim one for some reason. The same setup with a different extension (e.g. .md) works as expected, but I don't really understand why it doesn't for lua.
If I now add filetype plugin indent on to the top of my vimrc, textwidth is now read from lua.vim and correctly set to 80. So apparently specifically adding filetype plugin indent on does more than enable a setting. What does it do, and why does it fix the issue I had with lua.vim not being read correctly without it?
